# Trouble in adding images to mipmap folder in android studio

Tags: android, mipmaps

I am trying to add images to mipmap folder by Batch Drawable Import but images automatically come under drawable folder as shown in screenshot. Can anyone tell me how to import images under mipmap folder?

Screenshot::

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Open you file explorer and just move drawable files you want to move and paste into mipmap directory, and do not use any numerical number with image name.